# How do I write a Django ORM query for the reverse relationship in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, orm

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have the following two models in my models.py file ...

```
class Article(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
...


class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    elapsed_time_in_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
```

I would like to write a Django ORM query where I select articles have a stat that's at least 5 minutes (300 seconds) old.  However, I don't know how to reference the ArticleStat object from the Article object.  Unsurprisingly, this

```
Article.objects.filter(articlestat.elapsed_time_in_seconds.lte==300)
```

produces a

```
NameError: name 'articlestat' is not defined
```

error.

**Edit:** Per the answer, I changed my ArticleStat model to

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlestats')
```

and then I ran the below query getting the error displayed

```
Article.objects.filter(articlestat_set__elapsed_time_in_seconds__lte==300)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'articlestat_set__elapsed_time_in_seconds__lte' is not defined
```

Thought maybe there was an instance with plurality, so I tried an "s", but got an error ..

```
Article.objects.filter(articlestats_set__elapsed_time_in_seconds__lte==300)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'articlestats_set__elapsed_time_in_seconds__lte' is not defined
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The core issue here is the `NameError` for `articlestat` so I will address that first.

As explained in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) your backward relation name by default is defined as **`FOO_set`** which in your case means `articlestat_set`.

> If a model has a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), instances of the foreign-key model
>   will have access to a [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager) that returns all instances of the
>   first model. By default, this [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager) is named **FOO_set**,
>   where **FOO** is the source model name, lowercased.

If you prefer a different name you can do so by specifying a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) in your `ForeignKey` definition e.g.

```
class ArticleStat(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlestats')
    elapsed_time_in_seconds = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)
```

---

The second issue is how to properly follow relations which is explained quite extensively [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) which is why I will not go into detail about it in this answer. The gist is that instead of the `.` operator you want to use `__` (double underscore). The same goes for [`field lookups`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) which you need for comparison in this query.

With both these issues fixed your query should look like this:

```
Article.objects.filter(articlestat_set__elapsed_time_in_seconds__lte=300)
```

or with a custom `related_name` e.g. `related_name='articlestats'`:

```
Article.objects.filter(articlestats__elapsed_time_in_seconds__lte=300)
```

Comment: Really nice answer. Well explained.

Comment: @FynnBecker, Thanks for the thorough explanation.  I must be missing something really obvious because I added "related_name='articlestats'" into my ArticleStat model and then I ran the query, replacing "FOO" with "articlestat", but got the error "NameError: name 'articlestat_set__elapsed_time_in_seconds__lte' is not defined".  I also put the output in my question.

Comment: @Dave if you chose to go with a custom `related_name` you'll now have to use that in the query instead of **`FOO_set`** (which is just the default if you don't specify a `related_name`). I've updated the answer to include an example for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

`Article.objects.filter(articlestat__elapsed_time_in_seconds__lte=300)`

Please notice that Django queries work like *keywords (kwargs)* (i.e you can only pass a `filter_string=something` to the filter function).

You were passing an expression which python could not resolve (i.e python tried to find the `articlestat` variable name and then get its `elapsed_time_in_seconds` attribute etc)

Take a look at this for more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

Comment: This resulted in the error, "NameError: name 'articlestat__elapsed_time_in_seconds__lte' is not defined".  Note that the model ArticleStat has a one-to-one relation, defined in my model, to Article but not the other way around.  This is the root of my question.